# How to contourplot a function defined via findroot?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

when I use contourplot, the system will simplify the expression first with its parameters holded. However some expressions can not be simplified first without inputting parameters, for example,

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
f[x_, y_] := z /. FindRoot[g[x, y, z], {z, 0}];
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

will give warning informations

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {0. +x+y} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {z} = {0.}. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[g[x,y,z],{z,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nlnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[g[x,y,z],{z,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

whereas the output plot is right

[image]

but the following code will not generate warning information

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
f[x_, y_] := z /. FindRoot[g[x, y, z], {z, 0}];
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Question: how can I use the first example to generate the right plot without warning?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: See the answer [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restrict your function defintion to numeric values:

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := z /. FindRoot[g[x, y, z], {z, 0}];
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Otherwise Mathematica will consider f as an analytical function and will use as such. But `FindRoot` only works numerically.

Edit:
Of course you need to clear your function defintion before it can work.

```
Clear[f]
```

We can have a function that is defined for analytical values and the same time for numerical values.

Example to see what can happen:

```
h[x_] := x^4;
h[x_?NumericQ] := x^2;
h[a] /. a -> 2
h[2]
```

yields

> 16
>
> 4

You can check the function definitions by using `?functionName` (here `?f`)

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel? You may have the previous definitions of f still loaded.  f[x_,y_] and f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] are independent signatures so defining the second does not overwrite the first.

Comment: Restarting the kernel is not neccessary. Cleaning the function definitions suffices. BTW: The comment we are talking about is vanished by now.

Comment: Oh，it works.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

While I think the basic answer to this question has been given before in [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) and its linked questions, the underlying mathematics problem has a different approach.  The `ContourPlot` of $f(x,y)=a$ where $f$ is defined implicitly by $g(x, y, f(x, y)) = 0$ may be obtained by plotting the contour $g(x, y, a) = 0$.

There is a significant difference in these approaches.  `ContourPlot` will plot all functions $f$ defined by $g(x, y, f(x, y)) = 0$ over the plot domain.  `FindRoot` will find just one value for a given input $(x,y)$; moreover, the values are not guaranteed to lie on the same branch and the plot may appear discontinuous, nor is a found root guaranteed to be the root closest to the starting point passed to `FindRoot`.

For the OP's example problem, the code would be

```
ContourPlot[g[x, y, 1] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

An example to chosen to force the failure of `FindRoot`

```
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + Sin[z] + (z - 1) Sin[1/((z - 1)^2 + 10^-6)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]